# stringify null and undefined without stringify

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, stringify

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of JSON.stringify() with several primitive types, so far I have only managed to pass 'number' and 'string' (the easy ones) which in turn make, *function* and *empty string* also pass the test.

```js
function stringifier (input) {

  if (typeof input === 'number') return `${input}`;
  if (typeof input === 'string') return `"${input}"`;
  if (Array.isArray(input)) return `[${input.map(stringifier)}]`;

}
```

Now I'm trying to pass null and undefined but I just can't make it work... The parameter is passed different values to make all the tests pass (array, object, nested arr...).

Im currently using `if (typeof input === null) return String(input)` which I have tried separately and has worked. Have checked the type and its a string, I just don't understand why is not happening in the exercise. I'd like to have `'null'`, same as with `undefined`.

Also I have been trying to implement recursion on the Array with no success `if (Array.isArray(input)) return [${input.map(stringifier)}];` (with backticks).

Comment: Should be `if (typeof input === 'null')`

Comment: `(Array.isArray(input)) return [${input.map(json_encode)}]` - where is the recursion here?

Comment: by json_encode you mean stringifier itself?

Comment: `typeof null` is neither `null` not `"null"`, it's `"object"`.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) never returns `'null'`. You probably mean `if (input === null)`

Comment: also, encoding strings is actually by far the most complex problem you're going to face

Comment: @KonradLinkowski sorry!! A typo, the specified value for recursion is `stringifier`, not json_encode.

Comment: @gog precisely, I have done checks for all data types and it returns "object"... I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: `if (input === null)` hasn't helped either, doesn't pass the test

Comment: Alright, although `String(input)`should work (as checked everywhere online) I have re-tried `"" + input"`and does the job for both `null`and `undefined`... I'm still not understanding why though. One down.

Comment: `if (input === null)` _is_ the right way though. Make sure to get your order right, since it would also match an `if (typeof input === 'object')` test, it would have to go above such a test. Also, if something doesn't work, instead of just saying "it doesn't pass the test and I don't know why", you could use a debugger to look at the execution step by step and inspect the variables and expressions that get used, to be able to follow what's happening and see _why_ it doesn't work.

Comment: The recursion also looks correct, by the way. Again, "with no success" is not so helpful there, you should trace the execution in a debugger and see what's broken about it.

Comment: @CherryDT You are absolutely right, I should in fact provide else than just "not working", I'm just learning and how to provide concise info is still a bit hard for me.
So, I have taken few steps and this is what I got so far.
When going through debugger, on line `if (typeof input === 'number') return `${input}`;`it jumps elsewhere and throws an error:
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: That sounds like it happens because you run it inside a test library (probably Mocha). You could try running it in a separate file only for debugging, directly and not using Mocha, then you won't run into this problem during debugging. If you tried debugging it directly on the (presumably) challenge page - first of all, kudos, you learned an important skill. But, you will have an easier time by creating a separate project in an IDE (or even just an HTML+JS file or a JSFiddle) with your code and your own invocation of the code with the value you want to test and debug there.

Comment: If you _have_ to debug within Mocha and the timeout becomes an issue, you could instead resort to logging all kinds of things with `console.log` during execution (or, perhaps more dynamically, use a "logging breakpoint" in devtools which will log stuff when the line gets executed, without breaking - and stalling - execution)

Comment: @CherryDT That's exactly what, I'm doing these exercises to get into a bootcamp (as requested by school) and I think it uses Mocha. It goes to several other files and does some obscene amount of checks. I have already set the function in a separate .js file and with some proper testing it seems to work fine (except for `function`s and `undefined` inside an object). Let me share what craziness I have gone to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated function, most test do work on a different file than the provided by the school.

```js
function stringifier(input) {

  if (typeof input === 'function') return undefined;
  if (typeof input === 'number' || typeof input === 'boolean') return `${input}`;
  if (typeof input === 'string' || input === '') return `"${input}"`;
  if (input === null) return '' + input;

  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    let acc = "[";
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i] === undefined || typeof input[i] === 'function') input.splice(i, 1);
      acc += `${stringifier(input[i])},`;
    }
    acc = `${acc.substring(0, acc.length - 1)}]`;
    return acc;
  }
  if (typeof input === 'object') {
    let acc = "{";
    for (let key in input) {
      acc += `"${key}":${stringifier(input[key])},`;
    }
    acc = `${acc.substring(0, acc.length - 1)}}`;
    return acc;
  }
}

const test1 = { a: 'hello', b: 123, c: false, d: [1, 2], e: '', f: null, 7: undefined, 8: function () { } };
const test2 = [1, 2, 'hi', 'This is a string', null, undefined, [3, 4], function () { }, ''];
const test3 = 'test';
const test4 = 69;
const test5 = [[6, 9]];
const test6 = true;

console.log('test1;', stringifier(test1), '|', 'JSON:', JSON.stringify(test1));
console.log('test2;', stringifier(test2), '|', 'JSON:', JSON.stringify(test2));
console.log('test3;', stringifier(test3), '|', 'JSON:', JSON.stringify(test3));
console.log('test4;', stringifier(test4), '|', 'JSON:', JSON.stringify(test4));
console.log('test5;', stringifier(test5), '|', 'JSON:', JSON.stringify(test5));
console.log('test6;', stringifier(test6), '|', 'JSON:', JSON.stringify(test6));
```

I know it's cheap, but it kind of should do the job.